# Mvc3 Database first relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am working on a project with ASP.Net MVC3 EF4.1 and relationships between tables through foreign keys. I am using the database first approach and have three tables: Calendar, Calendar Users and Users. The relationship is that a Calendar can have many users and users can have many calendars.

When someone is creating the calendar he/she is also supposed to select the number of users that will have access to the calendar. But now when I am about to save the changes to the database in the controller thats when I get confused. In the generated classes there are also virtual ICollections that I suppose represent the foreign keys somehow. But I can't figure out how I am supposed to handle them? So how is it supposed to work? Should I be able to add the changes to the virtual ICollections and then just do db.SaveChanges() and it will work by itself or am I supposed too handle that manually?

If I am supposed to handle it manually should I then add the users, add the calendar and then add the keys in the CalendarUsers table to bind them together? I've seen some examples from code first where they have clarified the relationship by entering code in the OnModelCreating method but when using Database first it just contains:  `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();`? Hoping you perhaps can clarify it for me a bit.

Added the classes generated by the DBcontext Generator below:

```
public partial class Calendar
{
    public Calendar()
    {
        this.CalendarUsers = new HashSet<CalendarUser>();
    }

    public int CalendarId { get; set; }
    public string CalendarTitle { get; set; }
    public string CalendarDescription { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CalendarUser> CalendarUsers { get; set; }
}

public partial class CalendarUser
{
    public int CalendarUserId { get; set; }
    public int CalendarId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsAdmin { get; set; }

    public virtual Calendar Calendar { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Calendars = new HashSet<Calendar>();
        this.CalendarUsers = new HashSet<CalendarUser>();
    }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Calendar> Calendars { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CalendarUser> CalendarUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the created classes? (Not all details, just the properties that refer between the classes and the key and foreign key properties.) Important question is also if you have a separate class for `CalendarUsers` or if it is only a (many-to-many join) table without a class in the model.

Comment: CalendarUsers is a separate class. Maybe thats not a good approach?

Comment: The `CalendarUser` class is OK, you need it because of the `IsAdmin` flag. More confusing is the additional one-to-many relationship between `Calendar.User` and `User.Calendars`. Why do you have this? You said the relation is many-to-many and that's also in the model (`Calendar.CalendarUsers` and `User.CalendarUsers`). But what is the purpose of this additional one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Now I could imagine an interpretation: Is `Calendar.User` supposed to be the user who is the Admin for that calendar? Or can more than one user be Admins for a specific calendar?

Comment: The user ID associated with the calendar is the calendar owner. Several users will be able to be admin of the calendar and those are listed in CalendarUser but only one will be the owner of a Calendar. But the question remains. Do I save all the entries manually or is there some relation magic that I am supposed to use but haven't gotten working yet? Or is this a limitation to the Database first approach and I should change to code first?

Comment: No, there is no limitation in Database-First. I'm still unsure what your problem is. I've added an answer below, maybe that is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a new relationship between existing `Calendar` and `User` by setting the foreign key properties in a new instance of the `CalendarUser`:

```
var newCalendarUser = new CalendarUser
{
    CalendarId = calendarId,
    UserId = userId,
    IsAdmin = true // or false
};
dbContext.CalendarUsers.Add(newCalendarUser);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: When I try to add a new CalendarUser it just says that I don't have an empty constructor in the class. I could add such a constructor but each time I update my models I would have to remake the constructor. Thats why I'm thinking that I have missed something? Also I wonder if that is really how its meant to be done? Cause then I would have to keep track of all the relationships myself and all the coding that follows? What is the purpose of the public virtual ICollection<CalendarUser> then? Sorry for asking so many questions. I really appreciate the effort.

Comment: I get the following error: [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +117
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +247

Comment: @Janspeed: Why doesn't `CalendarUser` have a parameterless constructor? In your code xample above `CalendarUser` doesn't have a constructor at all (which means, it **has** a parameterless constructor by default). Or do you have a constructor with parameters in another part or this *partial* class? If yes, you need to add a parameterless constructor manually (just an empty constructor), because once you add a constructor with parameters in C#, the default parameterless constructor is removed.

Comment: @Janspeed: To your first comment: I still have problems to understand what exactly is the problem. Keep in mind that you don't have a many-to-many relationship but instead two one-to-many relationships because the intermediate entity `CalendarUser` is an entity and has "payload" due to the `IsAdmin` flag. So, you don't create directly a relationship between `Calendar` and `User` but between `Calendar` and `CalendarUser` and between `CalendarUser` and `User`. You can also use the collections but it doesn't make creating the relationship easier.

Comment: Ok seems like I actually talk about two problems at the same time. As for the error message the problem actually lies in my ViewModel and not the actual class I am trying to save which confused me. As for the many to many relationship what I'm looking for is a simpler solution than having to update the relationship between Calendar and Users manually each time I edit the calendar and its users. But I guess with the current database setup your answer is correct so I will mark it as such :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the navigation properties and EF will take care of the foreign keys for you. For sample code that handles updates in a similar many-to-many relationship, see the **Adding Course Assignments to the Instructor Edit Page** section of this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: It was a very interesting tutorial but I downloaded the sample and it also maps relations using the OnModelCreating method which makes me confused since I'm not quite sure I can use it working with database first? It feels like I'm missing some key knowledge here that will bind it all together. Maybe I have to abandone  Database first and move to code first but I would prefer not to?